# eclipse github desktop ignore error

Tags: eclipse, git, github, github-desktop

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    adminpage/.metadata/.log
    adminpage/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.safetable/org.eclipse.core.resources
    adminpage/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.launching.prefs
    adminpage/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.result/results
    adminpage/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
    adminpage/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide/com.genuitec.eclipse.aeri.server1/server-config.json
    adminpage/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide/org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide.server/server-config.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

Use the git hub desktop. 
The team members share their performance with a git, and every time they commit it, they are outweighed by the difficulty of printing. 
I've tried everything on the Internet, and I've tried to do this, and I've tried to do this, and I've tried to change this, and I'm not going to go through this. 
I'm creating a jsp based web source with Eclipse, but I don't know what's wrong with it. 
I'd like to get the help of millions of experts here.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, it would be easier to ignore the .metadata/ folder entirely:

```
git rm --cached -r adminpage/.metadata
echo "adminpage/.metadata/" >> .gitginore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "remote and ignore adminpage/.metadata"
git push
```

Repeat that in every branch where that folder is still tracked, and the error should not be seen again.